# Is there a time limit in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

I was playing a customized private game with my friends and the zone we had to capture was always *in fight* as we were always there and almost no one died so no team was getting points for the zone. At the end, after some minutes, we just ended the game with a 0% for each team.

So, is there an actual time limit in Overwatch games*?

*I'm refering to the game mode dominion(not sure about the name, I'm refering to the ones where both teams have to capture a zone) or the others when it goes into **Extra Time**

Comment: I've seen this happen on the practice map too.  After so much time passes, the server shuts down and kicks you back to the menu.

Comment: Hum.. but what if it happens on an actual game? Will the server just shut down? I mean, that could be a big problem in a ranked game

Comment: This is a great question! I don't know the answer, but I personally haven't experienced an actual time limit. We've gone over 5-8 minutes in overtime and it never kicked us, only waited for the game to finally find a winner

Comment: I don't think happens in public games. I think Blizzard's opinion is that private games tax the servers, which everyone is using, but not everyone can benefit from them. Thus, they shut down private games (training or custom) that last "too long."

Comment: I've also been kicked out of a Skirmish if the game couldn't find enough players to start the match for some time. Not sure what the actual time limit is, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible, but I'm refering to an actual game that's already being played.

Comment: There is a 30 minute time limit on practice. This can't hold true on Ranked though. I've had a game of volskya (hate that damn map) go on back and forth I think it was either 2 or 3 rounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Overwatch latest PTR patch notes](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20335231#patchnotes) :

> **Competitive Play**
>
> - Fixed a bug that could cause overtime to continue indefinitely on Assault maps

So yes, if you are unable to recapture a point, after a certain amount of time, the game will instantaneously end, giving the win to the team that currently controls the point.

Answer (score 2):

During the open beta I was in a match on Ilios (well) that seemed to hit a time cap. Both teams had reached 99%, but due to each side having a teleporter, the overtime was endless. Eventually the game just suddenly ended and the team in control at that time (my team) won the round. Everyone in the comments was rather confused. I can't remember exactly how long the match was, but it was long enough for people to start noticing.

Comment: Teleporters aren't endless, they die after six teleports -- or a couple of shots from the enemy team ;)

Are you sure the OT didn't just run out?